# Align <p></p> HTML center with an Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll

[image: VA website]

I have a passage for a website, written in HTML

How can I align (justify to center) with the Image?

```css
#main__img {
    text-align: center;
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
}

.main__content p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<img id="#main__img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRb3FlgJlyfSfAyDxdt6bGxrG4fOxz2sIEOog&usqp=CAU" />

<div class="main__content">
<p> Visualizing Abolition maps the suppression of the African slave trade by tracing nearly 31,000 records of correspondence exchanged between the British Foreign Office and British commissioners, ministers, naval officers, and representatives of foreign governments around the world over the course of the nineteenth century. It provides users with three resources. First, a database that lists the names of the senders, recipients, places of origin and destination, dates, as well as the subject of the letters when available. Second, essays exploring different topics related to the suppression of the traffic. Finally, a gallery of images that provides visual context for the information available on the website. These resources allow students and researchers to further understand the history of the suppression of the African slave trade and expand our knowledge of the largest coerced migration in history. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML and CSS to the question?

Comment: @cbalakus How about NOT suggesting deprecated code?

Comment: Put image INSIDE .main__content and move text-align:center to the DIV css

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with the CSS and a placeholder.com image

Comment: @mplungjan sorry this my first time to code in HTML and CSS

Comment: Click edit, scroll down click edit above snippet and add the img and other relevant tags

Comment: I updated your code. Please make it a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct HTML tool for this is the `figure element` - it has a display element (usually an image - but it can be anything) and a figcaption that is usually the first or last child of hte figure element. The figcaption contains the text related to the image.

The figure is used to collated visual elements with descriptions or related text and all the parts can be styled. In this case - its as simple as applying a text-align: center to the figure element as well as margin: 0 auto to center it in the page.to get the stylnig you are after.

```css
figure  {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center
}


figcaption {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img id="#main__img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRb3FlgJlyfSfAyDxdt6bGxrG4fOxz2sIEOog&usqp=CAU" />
  <figcaption>
    <p> Visualizing Abolition maps the suppression of the African slave trade by tracing nearly 31,000 records of correspondence exchanged between the British Foreign Office and British commissioners, ministers, naval officers, and representatives of foreign governments around the world over the course of the nineteenth century. It provides users with three resources. First, a database that lists the names of the senders, recipients, places of origin and destination, dates, as well as the subject of the letters when available. Second, essays exploring different topics related to the suppression of the traffic. Finally, a gallery of images that provides visual context for the information available on the website. These resources allow students and researchers to further understand the history of the suppression of the African slave trade and expand our knowledge of the largest coerced migration in history. </p>
  </figcaption>
<figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey add the following to your css:

```css
.main__content {
    width: 100%;
}
.main__content p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It will set the width of the paragraph same as the image, and the auto margin will set equal margin on both sides

**Alternatively** you can add both image and paragraph to the same container. It will be less prone to style breakage as follows:

```html
<div class="container">
  <img ...>
  <p>asdfsdfsdf</p>
</div>
```

and style:

```css
div.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.container img {
  width: 100%;
}
div.container p {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make both container the same width and use margin-left/right = "auto".

```css
#main__img {
    height: auto;
    width: 80%;
    display: block;

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.main__content p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: 400;

    width: 80%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="main__content">
<img id="main__img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/Astronotus_ocellatus.jpg" />

<p> Visualizing Abolition maps the suppression of the African slave trade by tracing nearly 31,000 records of correspondence exchanged between the British Foreign Office and British commissioners, ministers, naval officers, and representatives of foreign governments around the world over the course of the nineteenth century. It provides users with three resources. First, a database that lists the names of the senders, recipients, places of origin and destination, dates, as well as the subject of the letters when available. Second, essays exploring different topics related to the suppression of the traffic. Finally, a gallery of images that provides visual context for the information available on the website. These resources allow students and researchers to further understand the history of the suppression of the African slave trade and expand our knowledge of the largest coerced migration in history. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.main__content {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```